# How can one detect browser version via javascript WITHOUT using `navigator` and `navigator.userAgent`?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, client-hints

tldr; **Can one get the browser version from the front end without using navigator strings or Client Hints?**

So with [Google's announcement](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!msg/blink-dev/-2JIRNMWJ7s/yHe4tQNLCgAJ) about freezing the `navigator.userAgent` string, I've been tasked with going through a bunch of javascript libraries at work in an effort to replace browser sniffing (aka `userAgent`). I know, I know, we shouldn't use `userAgent` in the first place because it's a sack of confusion and lies, but I'm inheriting this code and not creating it. Luckily, a bunch of the use cases were dated (IE8-10, PhantomJS, Windows Phone) and I could remove them completely. Others I could figure out which features/intentions the original authors were using and I could swap their conditions for feature detection.

But some of the public facing logic is using `navigator.userAgent` to figure out the browser version and this has been more challenging to replace because everything I find on the interwebs related to this search points to using one of the `navigator` properties. I don't know how and why clients care which "version of Firefox a user is on" and I'm awaiting that answer, but in the meantime I'm trying to see if there is a solution out there that can detect browser version on the front end. I'm not restricting the answer to just javascript, if there is a CSS/HTML/JS combination, I'm all for it.

I'm also aware the Google says we should use [Client Hints](https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/) but that requires hitting the server which is out of scope for my task.

**Freezing plan** via the Google Announcement:

- Different parts of the UA string have different compatibility
  implications.
- Some parts of it, such as the browser version and the OS version, can
  be frozen without any backwards compatibility implications. Values
  that worked in the past will continue to work in the future.
- Other parts, such as the model (for mobile devices) and the OS
  platform, can have implications on sites that tailor their UI to the
  underlying OS or that target a very specific model in their layout. Such sites will need to migrate to use UA-CH.

If I am reading the second bullet here correctly, then the version parts of the `navigator` strings will be frozen and unreliable by Early June 2020.

Again, just so it's clear, **I know this *should* be replace by feature detection**, but I don't have full control over our clients and users and I'm just seeing if there is a solution out there. I have a feeling lots of folks will end up trying to solve this problem soon enough.

Comment: I'm… confused what you're asking. UA strings will start to lose their meaning in the coming months, but they'll stay available. Use Client Hints instead. *What* problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just added more info: Client Hints require pinging a server, which is out of scope for the task I'm working on. So the problem is can one get the browser version from the front end without using `navigator` strings or Client Hints?

Comment: This is probably going to be it, and it'll hopefully be ready by the time freezing begins: https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/#interface